# chrome overlaying dynamically generated content in spans

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a magento product page where the products with variable (configurable) prices change the price displayed above and changes the label text. so when you load it gives you
"from: " $lowestprice
and then when you pick a different option in the select it changes to that price above and removes the "from: " text from within the span.
if you then go back to the "pick an option" in the select the "from: " reappears.

the key is that in firefox when the "from:" is removed the price moves to the left (everything is left aligned) so that there isnt a big white space where the "from: " was...

in chrome when you go back to the default pick option the price overlays the "from: " (see pic)

this is the html

```
 <div class="mainprice">
   <div class="price-box">
       <span id="configurable-price-from-1552" class="label">
           <span class="configurable-price-from-label">From: </span>
       </span>
       <span id="product-price-1552" class="regular-price">
            <span class="price">$26.50</span>
       </span>
</div>
</div>
```

if i set a width to the label span then when the javascript removes the "from: " it looks like the price has a large left margin. i have also tried setting it as a table layout but the cell wont collapse when empty.

[image: image of price overlaying from line]

I really dont want to start hacking in the javascript or changing the layout of the html. my question is, is there a way to do this with css and make chrome behave the way firefox does, where it is working perfectly with just the spans. i have seen this problem with chrome before with table cells overlapping when a width wasnt specified.

Comment: It might help to setup a JSFiddle to include any CSS that could be causing issues.

Comment: What if you change to display:inline-block ?

Comment: inline-block doesnt help it.

Comment: at the moment the magento installation is loading a ton of css files additionally the js that is running this is all tangled together deep in magento. i am not sure i can set up an accurate fiddle